# How to implement correctly errors to check for env variables are set

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm tying in my NodeJS, Typescript App to set new config files which take .env variables and if one specific variable is not set to throw an error.

Next my config file and in the end the errors I did but need to know what should be the right way to do it and also where those errors are shown when a .env variable is missing.

```
import dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

export interface Config {
    //Server set
    serverPort: number;
    serverUrl: string;

    // Database set
    dbPort: number;
    dbHost: string;
    dbUsername: string;
    dbPassword: string;
    database: string;
}

const config: Config = {
    // Server
    serverPort: +process.env.SERVER_PORT || 4000,
    serverUrl: process.env.SERVER_URL,

    // Database
    dbPort: +process.env.DB_PORT || 5432,
    dbHost: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dbUsername: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    dbPassword: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
};

if (!config.serverPort) throw new Error('Environment variable "SERVER_PORT" is not defined');
if (!config.serverUrl) throw new Error('Environment variable "SERVER_URL" is not defined');

export { config };
```

I tried to implement the `if(...)` but I tried and seems not working in the above way, No error is shown nowhere if I do not set the .env and I would like to have a check for it.

My expectations are to have an if which checks for a single value of the env and show an error that says which one not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not working because of this line

```
serverPort: +process.env.SERVER_PORT || 4000,
```

That means that if there's no `process.env.SERVER_PORT` (or its value is boolean `false` alike) then you set `4000` as the value. Is the same as checking `!process.env.SERVER_PORT`.

So later when you check it with `!config.serverPort` is going always to have a valid value, as you already "fix" it before.

I don't understand why you add a default value in case there's no value, but later you check if there's a value.

I guess that what you want to check is a valid number value, so you must check that explicitly, something like:

```
if (!isFinite(config.serverPort) || config.serverPort < 1 || config.serverPort > 65535) throw whatever you want to throw
```

This will check that the value is a valid number and that fits inside valid port range (between 1 and 65535).

So, in short, you must check every property individually if you want to do specific checks for each one.

Comment: Ok I see but the second check should work in this case? The other check I understood thanks